# Move files with whitespaces in their names to folders named like the files' modification dates

Tags: bash, shell

I created a bunch of folders from modification dates, like these:
..
2012-11-29
2012-11-20
..

Now I want to move files into these folders, in case the have a modification date that equals the folders name. The files contain whitespace in their names.

If I run this I get a list that looks like the folder names:

```
find . -iname "*.pdf" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do stat -c "%.10y" "$file"; done
```

How do I take this output and use it in a script that moves these files like (pseudocode):

```
find . -iname "*.pdf" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do mv $<FILEWITHWHITESPACEINNAME> <FOLDERNAMEDLIKE $file stat -c "%.10y" "$file" > ; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -iname "*.pdf" -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    folder=$(stat -c "%.10y" -- "$file") || continue  # store date in variable
    [[ $file = ./$folder/$file ]] && continue         # skip if already there
    mkdir -p -- "$folder" || continue                 # ensure directory exists
    mv -- "$file" "$folder/"                          # actually do the move
  done
```

- To read a NUL-delimited name correctly, use `IFS=` to avoid losing leading or trailing spaces, and `-r` to avoid losing backslashes in the filename. See [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- Inside your shell loop, you have shell variables -- so you can use one of those to store the output of your `stat` command. See [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)
- Using `--` signifies end-of-arguments, so even if your `find` were replaced with something that could emit a path starting with a `-` instead of a `./`, we wouldn't try to treat values in `file` as anything but positional arguments (filenames, in the context of `stat`, `mkdir` and `mv`).
- Using `|| continue` inside the loop means that if any step fails, we don't do the subsequent ones -- so we don't try to do the `mkdir` if the `stat` fails, and we don't try to do the `mv` if the `mkdir` fails.

Comment: Thank you for doing the work to improve the question! The work you put into the revision made it easy to answer.